# Streamlit Snowflake app going to sleep after 5-10minutes even if code is running

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

So I currently have an app running into Snowflake streamlit, and no matter what I do inside it, even if code is running, it keeps going to sleep while I am using it after about 5-10minutes, and loose all the analysis I am doing because it cleans everything and reloads from start.

[image: You can see it says running but the app sleeps]

I even tried calling a count, that prints a number every 1 second on the screen, so that I am sure something is active all the time, but still, the app goes to sleep.
Someone knows how I can fix this or make the sleeping time bigger ?

Comment: If your app is running something in the background (queries or anything) then it should not go to sleep. It should only sleep on idle. I would suggest you open a case with Snowflake support for this as they may need to look further into it.

Comment: Do you by any chance have an update on this topic? @Paulo